# How to add location marker on MapKit SwiftUI and showing satellite view?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

**How to add a location marker on latitude longitude in SwiftUI using MapKit?**

I am able to see location, but how can I show a marker on location with customs icons ?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {  
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
         MKMapView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26.801, longitude: 75.805)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct MaoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989013/adding-a-mapmarker-to-mapkit-in-swiftui-2

Comment: Why do you use the UIKit detour? MapKit can do that natively in SwiftUI.

Comment: hi vadian how do it natively and also how i show the satellite view

Answer (score 1):

You can show the point marker by creating a `MKPointAnnotation` first, then calling `addAnnotation()`.
Example:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        uiView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26.801, longitude: 75.805))
    }
}
```